# I have multiple panels on same form and I want Passing a value between 2 panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel

I have multiple panels on the same form and I want Passing a value between 2 panels

I want to enter Username in the first panel and Show as Label in next panel

please not in between 2 Form but 2 Panels.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Guna.UI.Lib.GraphicsHelper.ShadowForm(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub GunaButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GunaButton1.Click
    pnLogin.BringToFront()
    GunaTransition1.Hide(pnLogin)
End Sub

Private Sub GunaButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub GunaGradientButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub GunaTextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GunaTextBox1.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You have to show us your code.  Generally, it shouldn't matter if controls are in different containers.  We don't know what's stopping you from passing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the controls are in the same Form, then the container they are within is irrelevant.

The code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

You need to change the control names to what you have on your form for the Button, TextBox and Label.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the variable in form class scope and use it! can you explain more details?

Update:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
   Lable.text = TextBox.text
EndSub
```

Comment: Okay Thanks for your comment
I have 2 Panels in one Form 
in The First panel, I have one **TextBox** and one **Button**
and the next panel, I have one **Label**
So, I want when I write something in the **TextBox** and Click Button Show it in next Panel in **Label**

Comment: TextBox and Lable and Panels are Form Controls. they are separated visually, but not in concept! after naming you textbox and label, on button click sub write this code Lable.text = TextBox.text